# Book, probably published before the 1980s, about a pair of teenage girls (twins?) raised by dolphins and slowly integrating into society

Tags: story-identification

I picked up a copy of this in my grandmother's house, probably 10-20 years ago. I think my mother said it belonged to my aunt Mary, who probably would have read it around the 1970s (high school / college age). The primary characters were a pair of teenage girls who had an older male professor as their guardian. I'm pretty sure the girls had long blonde hair and blue eyes. I don't remember if the girls were feral children raised by dolphins or if they were part of an experiment by the professor, but they were amazing swimmers who could hold their breath for longer than any normal human. Other than that, I just have a few scenes dancing around it my head. First, the professor kept the girls on a boat, presumably so that they could be closer to water. Second, there was a scene where one of the girls put on makeup to try to be normal, and went off on a date. Her sister observes from a hiding place. The date in question sees the sister watching and assumes that this is a sign that they're both interested and he gets more aggressive. She interprets her date's kiss as an attack and goes off of the side of the boat, leading him to think that he killed her (my vague memory is that said date might have been an assistant to the professor or he might have just been a local townsperson).

The girls might have had a psychic connection with each other, but I'm less sure about that. Unfortunately, I read this over a decade ago, and I don't think I even got to finish the book. The front cover had one of the girls on the boat and I want to say that the title talking about them as "dolphin girls". It might have been part of a series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely *Daughters of the Dolphin* by Roy Meyers, published in 1968. The second book in a trilogy. The first book is *Dolphin Boy*, John, whose mother's exposure to radiation, allowed him to live essentially as a dolphin.He is raised by a female dolphin after being accidentally tossed into the sea as an infant.
There's is not enough online to get details of *Daughters*, but what I remember of the book, I think matches your question.

[image]

Comment: That cover looks vaguely familiar... I've requested a copy via Interlibrary Loan and I look forward to learning whether this is a match.

Comment: I'm about a third of the way through the second book and the focus is squarely on Triton, which doesn't gibe with my memory of the date being right near the beginning, but I will read on, and I'm requesting the third book on the off-chance that it's a better match.

Comment: Wow... the third book goes for $20+ on EBay, and even the Interlibrary Loan system wants $10 at the least for the privilege of borrowing it. It does seem like the best match so far, but I may wait until I visit my grandparents' house to see if it's still in the bookcase.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure you're right in that it's the third book, so I'm giving you the acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Music_of_Dolphins comes up in a quick google search. A bit later than your dates though seeing as it is from the mid 90's

Comment: I distinctly remember it being a pair of girls, but it's a good suggestion.

Comment: Well the wiki article references a second girl named Shay that was a friend and I thought that might be the second girl. Dunno though.

Comment: I'll try to get a copy from the local library and check.

Comment: I'm about a fifth of the way through and it does not match. It's in a first person epistolary narration versus the third-person literary narration I remember. And Shay is a different feral child at the treatment center. Thank you for the suggestion though. It does seem like a good book.